# Graph theory problem: n-dimensional cube

Tags: graph-theory

Let $Q_n$ be the $n-dimensional$ cube graph:  Its vertices are all the $n-tuples$ of $0$ and $1$ with two vertices being adjacent if they dier in precisely one position.For example, in $Q_3$, the vertices $(1,0,0)$ and $(1,0,1)$ are adjacent because they differ only in the third position.Show that $Q_n$is bipartite.

Can anybody help me with this question please?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Think of the defining properties of a bipartite graph. In particular, what do you know about the length of cycles in a bipartite graph?

Comment: I don't get it, the length should be even, that is all I can think of.  @megas

Comment: Indeed. And most importantly, if you can show that all cycles have even length, then the graph is bipartite.
In your case, are there any odd cycles? In other words, if you start from any vertex, can you complete any cycle back to that same vertex in odd number of steps?